# How to colour a table with opaque colour such that no text and no lines are visible?

Tags: tables, color, colorbox, transparent

I am iterating a latex file and want to colour all the tables green such that no text or no lines are visible. I tried using "transparent" but it fades the colour along with the text. I want the colour to be the green and no text should be visible?
My code is

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{green}{
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\color{green}` before the table will color the lines and text

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{green}{
\color{green}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether I understood your question correctly or not. The following typesets its argument inside a box and outputs a green box which has the same size as the argument would have had.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{grabbox}

\newsavebox\overgreenboxBox
\newcommand*\overgreenbox
  {%
    \grabbox\overgreenboxBox\hbox
      {%
        \textcolor{green}
          {%
            \vrule
              height \ht\overgreenboxBox
              depth \dp\overgreenboxBox
              width \wd\overgreenboxBox
          }%
      }%
  }

\begin{document}
\overgreenbox{\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}a&b\\c&d\\\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can colourise both cell background and text using the same colour for text and background. If you load the [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array)-package, you can define a new column type G (for green). `\arrayrulecolor` colourise the lines. Depending of your goals; with this approach you can change each of the three coloured item individually:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{G}{>{\cellcolor{green}\color{green}}{c}}
\arrayrulecolor{green} % Colourise rule for all tabulars, move inside the tabular environment to limit scope

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| * {2}{G|}}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]